# GLUE - o93.getDynamicFrame. com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver ERROR

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, pyspark, jdbc, aws-glue

I am trying to connect to Mysql. I have uploaded the corresponding java jar we are using , which is **mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar** , I uploaded to s3 bucket. I am using the following code to access to Mysql and I am failing with the Error

> An error occurred while calling o93.getDynamicFrame.
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

```
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext, SparkConf
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
import time
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType
import  boto3 
import json



sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

spark.conf.set("jars", "s3://xxxxx/jdbc-drivers/mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar")

client = boto3.client("secretsmanager" , region_name = "eu-west-1")
get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId = "etl-1")

secret = get_secret_value_response["SecretString"]
secret=json.loads(secret)

username = secret.get("mysql_username")
password = secret.get("mysql_password")
url = secret.get("mysql_url")
table = secret.get("mysql_table")



connection_mysql_options_source_session = {
    "url": url,
    "dbtable": table,
    "user": username,
    "password": password,
    "customJdbcDriverS3Path": "s3://xxxxx/jdbc-drivers/mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar",
    "customJdbcDriverClassName": "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"}
    


# Read from JDBC databases with custom driver
df_session = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type="mysql", connection_options=connection_mysql_options_source_session)


df_session.printSchema()
```

In job details section, I have referred to jar libs:
[image]

And I didn't define any connection in the connection section of job properties. I can't figure out why I am getting this error.

**The strange thing is that I can connect with Crawler, data catalogue and also direct connection to the same server, but via Notebook & script I can't.**

Comment: For version 5.1.49 of the MySQL Connector JAR, the driver class name is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. The driver class only moved to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` from version 6 onwards. Remove `.cj` from the driver class name and try again.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Thanks for your response, I have tried and it return this error:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o118.load.
: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Comment: Well, that's progress, your code is now loading the database driver when it wasn't before. The error you're now getting is a common error which indicates that your code is unable to connect to the database because the networking isn't set up to allow the connection to be made. It's difficult to help any further with no further information on the networking setup in your AWS environment.

Comment: thank you @LukeWoodward I open other issue for this